# Multiple Views in same XIB. issue when rotate view and change view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, rotation

i have a problem.
my viewController's Xib has multiple UIView.
the app starts in portrait mode and i can rotate it into landscape.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES; // (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

when i'm in landscape mode and i change view pressing a UIButton, the "new" view still remain in Portrait mode..
here's the code to change view:

```
-(IBAction) gotogame
{
     self.view = gameView;
}
```

i want to see a correct rotated view when i change view
how can do it?

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your method

```
-(IBAction) gotogame
{
     self.view = gameView;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: ok done but it rotate me the iPhone (simulator) but the view didn't rotate :(

Comment: have you created the view in landscape mode or portrait?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it is working for me:

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] init];
newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
newView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```